# Tooltip on the Similar questions suggestion box in the ask question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, tooltips, similar-questions

In the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, when hover on the answer box for the post in the Similar questions suggestion box, the tooltip is not understandable.

For example: When hover on the answer count it is showing the correct tooltip. But when hover on the answer or answers, it is showing the tooltip as "One" only. And for the 0 answers it is showing as "0".

**What is the tooltip actaully referring?**

When hover on the 2 answers:

> [image: Hover on 1/2 answers]

When hover on the 0 answers:

> [image: Hover on 0 answers]

GIF for the same:

[image: GIF]